# Exception Mongo Server and Meteor query disagree how many documents match your query

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-publications

This is basically the exception i have on my Meteor project.

I have a `Meteor.publish` with a simple query:

```
Meteor.publish('test', function(x) { 
    return Test.find({ a: x });
});
```

Then i have this on my client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('test', 'TEST');
```

This is the result of my console:

```
Exception in defer callback: Error: The Mongo server and the Meteor
query disagree on how many documents match your query. Maybe it is 
hitting a Mongo edge case? The query is: { a: "Test" }
```

Meteor version: `1.6.1`

Mongo version: `3.4.10`

Meteor (internal package) version: `1.3.0`

Mongo (internal package) version: `1.4.2`

I would like a solution that doesn't need to update any versions. Thank you!

Comment: Please differentiate between Meteor and Mongo versions and the respective package versions. You included the package versions, but you should also include the Meteor version (`$ cat .meteor/release`) and the mongo version (in dev mode `$ meteor mongo` and then `$ db.version()` , on a production server `$ mongod --version` )

Comment: I've checked the versions: `meteor 1.6.1` and `mongo 3.4.10`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the supported Mongo version for meteor 1.3.0 is mongo 2.4, 2.6 or 3.0.

Is their a reason why you can't update both meteor and mongo ?

Comment: I've posted the versions i have on the project, i prefer not to update for now, because of the other packages i'm using